# How to iterate over all elements in an SVG with either a fill or color in Snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

How can I iterate over all elements of an SVG image that have either a fill or color attribute using the Snap.svg JS library? I only want to modify the fill or color of elements that already have this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css selector and selectAll() method to iterate over the results.

Example

```
s.selectAll('rect[stroke="#123456"]').forEach( function( el ) { console.log( el )} );
```